# Does using Eevee with heavy rendering make Blender lag like in Cycles?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, performance

I use blender 2.79. When I render really heavy objects blender starts to lag, although my PC specs are good. Does Eevee do the same? I have seen on youtube that it is much faster, but what about very heavy stuff?

Comment: Cycles and Eevee are completely different approaches. Cycles uses path tracing while Eevee is a real time 3D engine. What you describe as "lag" is just the aspect of a more hardware-demanding technology. Both engines have their pros and cons. Your question doesn't really give a hint about what you mean by "heavy stuff". In order to receive a good answer, you might want [to elaborate on that](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/180356/edit) a little more.

Comment: @metaphor_set today i was rendering a planet with lava and atmosphere (clouds) on the surface now what happened that blender start to lag and i couldn't finish the project because it was so heavy

Comment: And...? I really don't understand where you are going with that. Please, [edit your question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/180356/edit) and don't use the comments to elaborate. If you already have a render, why not post that as a screenshot? It's really tedious to worm information out of people that should be in the question in the first place.

Comment: Hello :). I use Eevee for viewport previews, and even scenes with 800k vertices and multiple 4k textures are smooth. It's much much faster than Cycles, and has almost no noise.